# How should i run a async function in sync function in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I have a vue project that use CDN to getting it libs for running. Now I want to add a integrity property on the script label to verify the script it pull from CDN. And I want the code automatic generate the hash of script and insert is to the dist when i build the project.

**I want a some sync function like this:**

```js
function integrityWapper ({ css, js }) {
  const hash = require('crypto-js').SHA384
  const icss = []; const ijs = []
  for (const i in css) {
    icss.push([css[i], hash(GettingScriptContentFromWeb(css[i]))])
  }
  for (const i in js) {
    ijs.push([js[i], hash(GettingScriptContentFromWeb(js[i]))])
  }
  return { icss, ijs }
}
```

Obviously, this function cannot be async cause i am trying to generate config for `vue.config.js`, so the `GettingScriptContentFromWeb` function must also be sync.
**Is there a way turn call async function(i mean axios.get) in sync function and wait it to finish?**

Update:
No, i can't just rewrite the upstream cause i need export the result in `vue.config.js`, this is some code i currently use:

** vue.config.js **

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  integrity: true,
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: 'src/main.ts',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      CDN: cdnConfig.use ? cdnConfig.list : null
    }
  }
})

//cdnConfig.list is like this:
list: {
  css: [
    [
      'https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/element-plus/2.2.13/index.css',
      'sha384-WdBufJjVUMBy2e6mTgtUbbYZvZg7vdYW3ijXdfg4jglZAehE17bPFaxNMhFXuH1Z'
    ]
  ],
  js: [
    [
      'https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.37/vue.global.prod.min.js',
      'sha384-MB7auY3xTNj+3Hk53DrKFyXN7Djh50mLDesxCDPr4XENv8gK06a3RqhmkXBfcPFh'
    ]
  ]
}
```

Or can somebody tell me how can i rewrite the part that vue and webpack read these config?
Should i just write this script in a other file and i run it before `vue-cli-service build` in `npm run build`, or i try to use package like **deasync** or **sync-kit**?

Comment: No.  You cannot make an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one in nodejs.  You will have to rewrite this code to be asynchronous and expect the asynchronous operations to work asynchronously.

Comment: if something is asynchronous, you can't get the result synchronously

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way turn call async function(i mean axios.get) in sync function and wait it to finish?

No, there is not.  `axios.get()` is asynchronous and you cannot get its result synchronously.

You will have to rewrite your code to use an asynchronous design.  Probably, `GettingScriptContentFromWeb()` needs to return a promise and `integrityWrapper()` needs to use that promise and also needs to return a promise.  The caller of `integrityWrapper()` then needs to use `.then()` or `await` on the promise that `integrityWrapper()` will return to get the resolved value.

For example, if you changed `GettingScriptContentFromWeb()` to return a promise that resolves to it's value, then you could do this:

```
async function integrityWapper ({ css, js }) {
  const hash = require('crypto-js').SHA384
  const icss = []; const ijs = []
  for (const i in css) {
    icss.push([css[i], hash(await GettingScriptContentFromWeb(css[i]))])
  }
  for (const i in js) {
    ijs.push([js[i], hash(await GettingScriptContentFromWeb(js[i]))])
  }
  return { icss, ijs }
}

integrityWrapper(...).then(result => {
    // use the asynchronously retrieved result here
}).catch(err => {
    // got some error here
});
```

P.S. if `css` or `js` are arrays, then you should be using `for/of` to iterate arrays, not `for/in`.  If they are objects, then you can use `for/in` to iterate their enumerable properties.

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with http api's the result is always going to be asynchronous. From the context, i am assuming you want to execute this script when you are building the project, something like `yarn dostuff`.

This can be achieved like by wrapping the async function in a self executing function

`index.js`

```
async function integrityWapper ({ css, js }) {
  const hash = require('crypto-js').SHA384
  const icss = []; const ijs = []
  for (const i in css) {
    icss.push([css[i], hash(await GettingScriptContentFromWeb(css[i]))])
  }
  for (const i in js) {
    ijs.push([js[i], hash(await GettingScriptContentFromWeb(js[i]))])
  }
  return { icss, ijs }
}

const executor = (async ()=>{
  await integrityWapper({
    css: process.env.CSS,
    js: process.env.JS
  });
})();

export default executor;
```

And then add a script in `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "dostuff": "node index.js",
    "custom-build": "yarn dostuff && yarn build"
  },
```

Something on the lines of above

Hope i made sense